# Chamando função NODEJS retorna 400

Tags: node.js, funções, api

Tenho um método REST que chama uma function. Esta function verifica se a `vaccine` já existe no banco de dados, do contrário cria e retorna para o método que a chamou. Porém, ao chamar o método REST estou recebendo um erro `400`.

No console não é registrado nada. Alguém poderia indicar o erro?

```
function getVaccineByName(name, dose, avoidedDiseases) {

  Vaccine.find({ name: name }).then((existingVaccine) => {
    if (existingVaccine) {
      return existingVaccine
    } else {
      const newVaccine = new Vaccine({
        name: name,
        date: new Date().toString(),
        dose: dose,
        avoidedDiseases: avoidedDiseases
      })
    
      newVaccine.save()
        .then(vaccine => {
          return vaccine
        })
        .catch(err => JSON.stringify(err))
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('inner err');
    throw err
  })
}
```

Comment: Essa resposta (`400`) significa que o servidor não consegue entender sua requisição, pois existe uma sintaxe ou estrutura inválida. Precisamos de mais informacoes para entender o erro, mas creio que pode ser erro na requisição, na estrutura do objeto de envio, creio eu.

Comment: Posso está enganado, mas nada aparece se você colocar um `console.log()` no `err` aqui: `.catch(err => JSON.stringify(err))` em vez de `JSON.stringify`?